# How to put correct Marathi/Hindi text on Image using PIL in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-imaging-library

```
import os
from PIL import *
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from PIL import Image
from PIL import ImageFont
from PIL import ImageDraw 

# background png stored in list
os.chdir('D:\\My Image Processing\\Image Design\\IMAGE PROCESSING\\back\\BLACK FONT BG')
back = os.listdir()

for b in range(len(back)):
     #background
    b1 = Image.open(f"D:\\My Image Processing\\Image Design\\IMAGE PROCESSING\\back\\BLACK FONT BG\\{back[b]}")

    # text
    draw = ImageDraw.Draw(b1)

    # Font
    font33 = ImageFont.truetype("D:\\My Image Processing\\Image Design\\IMAGE PROCESSING\\fonts\\Poppins-Medium.ttf", 80)
    
    x = "हार पत्करण माझ ध्येय नाही कारण मी बनलोय जिंकण्यासाठी."
    draw.text((310,220), values[i].center(1), x,font=font33, align='center', stroke_width=1, stroke_fill=(0,0,0))


    b1.save(f'D:\\My Image Processing\\Image Design\\IMAGE PROCESSING\\output\\BLACK OUTPUT MARATHI\\img.png')
```

output:

[image: The word जिंकण्यासाठी is spelled incorrectly]

I am trying to put text on the image I was able to put English text on the image but when I tried to put text of other language such as hindi and marathi it is showing me various kind of errors such as wrong spelling & wrong syntax of that language... I tried various fonts and size but unable to over come this problem... So I ask for your help to overcome this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Hey I had used pyvips to write hindi/devanagari text on an image using python.

First of all i installed pyvips, but when you import it will give you an error, so to overcome that issue you have to download file from pyvips and put it in your environment variable path and than you can put the text on image.

Actually I wrote article which contains step by step solution... I am sure this will help you.

https://www.infinitycodex.in/how-to-put-hindi-text-on-images-using

```
# IMPORTS  
 
 import os  
 import pyvips  
 import textwrap  
 from PIL import *  
 import pandas as pd  
 from PIL import Image  
 from PIL import ImageFont  
 from PIL import ImageDraw   
 

 # MAKE A FUNCTION  
 
 def bgoutput(filename, text):  
 
   rendered_text, feedback = pyvips.Image.text(text,   
                         font='Mangal', fontfile='Mangal Regular.ttf',   
                         width=900, height=900,   
                         autofit_dpi=True) 
 
   rendered_text = rendered_text.gravity('centre', 1500, 1500)  

   image = rendered_text.new_from_image([0, 0, 0]).bandjoin(rendered_text)  
   image.write_to_file(f'{filename}.png') 
 
 # GENERATE OUTPUT 1   

 text = "परिस्थितियां विपरीत हो तो कुछ लोग टूट जाते हैं, और कुछ लोग रिकॉर्ड तोड़ देते हैं..!!"  
 bgoutput('new', text)  

 # COMBINE OUTPUT 1 WITH BACKGROUND IMAGE  

 img = Image.open('new.png')   
 b1 = Image.open('bg_img.png')  
 img = img.resize((1000,1000))  
 b1.paste(img,(50,50), mask=img)  

 # GENERATE FINAL OUTPUT  

 b1.save("final.png")
```